# Data Scraping Using Spotifyr

Tags: r, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to scrape music from my own spotify playlist using the R package spotifyr. However, I keep running into an issue when executing certain functions such as get_user_playlist. Whenever I execute these functions I get "Waiting for authentication in browser..." and then a browser window opens up with text reading "Illegal Scope". Can anybody help me solve this issue?

I can run other functions such as "get_artist_audio_features", but I cannot run functions that will scrape data from my specific playlists.

If this question is not allowed on here please let me know and I will remove! I've attached code below.

```
library(spotifyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(lubridate)
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENTID')
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET')

access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()

my_id <- 'ID'

my_plists <- get_user_playlists(my_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some default spotifyr scope is giving the error

1. Save your secrets:

   ```
   Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
   Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
   ```
2. Specify the scopes you need:

   ```
   print(spotifyr::scopes)
   scopes = c(
       "user-library-read",
       "user-read-recently-played",
       "playlist-read-private",
       "playlist-read-collaborative",
       "user-read-private"
   )
   ```
3. With scopes, you will build your authorization

   ```
   auth = spotifyr::get_spotify_authorization_code(Sys.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"),
                                           Sys.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                                           scopes)
   ```
4. You can now get your playlists:

   ```
   playlists = spotifyr::get_user_playlists(SPOTIFY_ID, limit, offset, authorization = auth)
   ```